# Bean property 'myDataSource' is not writable or has an invalid setter method

Tags: spring

Getting the following error with this configuration in Spring beans:

```
<bean name="/login.htm" class="com.virtusa.web.EmployeeController">
  <property name="service" ref="service"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="service" class="com.virtusa.service.ServiceIMP">
  <property name="dao" ref="EmployeeDAO"></property>
</bean> 

<bean id="EmployeeDAO" class="com.virtusa.dao.EmployeeDAO">
  <property name="myDataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
</bean>
```

My spring config file is as follows:

```
private DataSource myDataSource;
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

public void setDataSource(DataSource myDataSource) {
    this.myDataSource = myDataSource;
     this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(myDataSource);
 }
```

my dao

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have `property name="myDataSource"`, your setter needs to be named `setMyDataSource()` rather than `setDataSource()`.