# Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'dataSource' of bean class Bean property 'dataSource' is not wri

Tags: spring, spring-jdbc

I followed many links like [Bean property 'myDataSource' is not writable or has an invalid setter method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134319/bean-property-mydatasource-is-not-writable-or-has-an-invalid-setter-method), but did not solved my issue.

I am getting the below error:

Could somebody please point out what the issue is ? I did nothing much so far.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myBIllingService' defined in class path resource [config/context.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'dataSource' of bean class [com.hp.service.MyBIllingService]: Bean property 'dataSource' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.hp.App.main(App.java:15)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'dataSource' of bean class [com.hp.service.MyBIllingService]: Bean property 'dataSource' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1064)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:922)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:82)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:62)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1489)
    ... 13 more
```

The code below:

```
public class MyBIllingService {
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public MyBIllingService(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
}
```

context.xml

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.hp.*" />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />

    <!-- connect to ORACLE database -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}" />
        <property name="url" value="${spring.datasource.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${spring.datasource.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${spring.datasource.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id = "myBIllingService" class="com.hp.service.MyBIllingService">
        <property name = "dataSource" ref = "dataSource" />
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are wiring the dataSource to your MyBillingService through XML configuration.  Why are you trying to Autowire also through the constructor?  Try removing Autowired from your MyBillingService cinstructor.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing below issue

**org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'dataSource' of bean class [com.rcu.javatpoint.FanDAOImpl]: Bean property 'dataSource' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?**

Make sure you have added getter/setter for bean class which you want to create bean id.
When you add getter/setter method you wont get this error.